# How to scroll up custom pixels when scrolled to a tab on page reload or using a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I'm using this Bootstrap panel:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-1" role="tab">First Panel</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-2" role="tab">Second Panel</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-3" role="tab">Third Panel</a>
        </li>
    </ul><!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs-1" role="tabpanel">
            <p>First Panel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-2" role="tabpanel">
            <p>Second Panel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-3" role="tabpanel">
            <p>Third Panel</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I added this script to redirects me to a specific tab on page reload:

```
    // Javascript to enable link to tab
    var hash = location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');  // ^ means starting, meaning only match the first hash
    if (hash) {
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
    }
```

Now this works fine and properly redirects to a specific tab when I go to a URL like this:

```
https://sitename.com/page#tabs-2
```

But I need to load the page with `100px` upper.

I mean I have to scroll up the page `100px`, when users wants to load a tab-pane.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code which redirects you to Bootstrap panel and also move `-100`px vertically to the up:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if(window.location.hash != "") {
            $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').click();
                window.scrollBy(0, -100); // 0 pixels horizontal 
        }
});
```